# Solr deployment strategies for 100% Up Time while creating whole index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet, uptime

I'm working on a Solr 3.6 with ASP.net MVC3 e-commerce project.

I've an index of appx. 1 lac products in Solr. There is some changes in requirements, and we need to rebuild the whole index. Whole indexing is taking almost 1 & half hour during which site needs to be down.

How can I rebuild the index and also keep the site live which serving contents from older index. What is best practices to reduce down time while rebuilding the whole index. I wish I can do it with 100% uptime.

**Edit**
I'm storing a several URLs into Solr data as stored field and hence, which are dynamically generated while adding data into Solr. If I deploy application on different sub domain like test.example.com then it takes wrong URL, wherein it will only work with example.com. So hosting an another application is not an option for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leverage the concept of [multiple cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) in Solr and thereby have a live core that users are currently searching against and a standby core where you can make schema changes, re-index, etc. Then using the [SWAP](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) command you can switch the live and standby cores without any user downtime. The swap will be handled internally by Solr and your users will never notice a difference.

Comment: thank you, now working on implementing this. This is great. thank you.

Comment: What about data directory? all cores should have different data directories...??

Comment: Yes, you should have a different data directory for each core. Checkout the /example/multicore folder in the Solr download to see how they recommend the structure should be setup. (In each coreX folder there is a conf and there will also be a data folder for the index). See the solr.xml file for how to configure solr for the folder per core settings.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, there are several ways to correctly solve this problem:

1. Do not rebuild the whole index - just update necessary records on-the-fly when they changes, Solr can do it pretty simple
2. Create 2 Solr instances on different ports and use them one after one. When first is rebuilding, on the second you can use old index. And when first is rebuilt, you can use it until the index on second instance is rebuilt.
3. Add boolean field to your index named, for example, "old_index". And whem reindexing starts, update all currrent records and set old_index=1, then write somewhere in configuration that you looking for records with old_index==1. Than start reindexing, than delete old records. It can be done with Solr`s deleteByQuery and either atomatic update in Solr 4.x or manual update.